# Pass Type as a Constructor and use it as a generic for provider package

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a child widget:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final provider;

  MyWidget({Key key, @required this.provider});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = Provider.of<provider>(context);
  }

}
```

That I use multiple times from a parent widget:

```
class Parent extends StatelessWidget {

  ...
  children: <Widget>[
    ChangeNotifierProvider<Myproviderone>(
      builder: (context) => Myproviderone(),
      child: MyWidget(MyProviderone),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<Myprovidertwo>(
      builder: (context) => Myprovidertwo(),
      child: MyWidget(MyProvidertwo),
    ),
  ],
  ...

}
```

I am using provider package. Basically I want to pass the Type Myproviderone/Myprovidertwo to be used as a generic inside `Provider.of<>` How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `MyWidget` a generic class:

```
class MyWidget<T> extends StatelessWidget {    
  MyWidget({Key key});

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = Provider.of<T>(context);
  }
}
```

and then build it from the outside like that:

```
class Parent extends StatelessWidget {
  children: <Widget>[
    ChangeNotifierProvider<Myproviderone>(
      builder: (context) => Myproviderone(),
      child: MyWidget<MyProviderone>(),
    ),
  ],
}
```

Comment: You may want to do <T extends MyProviderInterface> though